# Get Tweets from Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'am trying to get tweets from a twitter acount but only using angularjs, whitout php or another language.
I have tried but I couldn't. and also I have to use the 1.1 twitter api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.We don't support or recommend performing OAuth directly through
> Javascript -- it's insecure and puts your application at risk. The
> only acceptable way to perform it is if you kept all keys and secrets
> server-side, computed the OAuth signatures and parameters server side,
> then issued the request client-side from the server-generated OAuth
> values.
>
> 2.The OAuth access token will need to be part of the call and
> the oauth_token_secret will need to be used to compute the signature
>
> 3.No

from [Twitter Dev site](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5025)